# Solve complex integral of $1/(z^5+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Do you have any suggestions how should i approach this integral? Here the contour is a circle with radius 2 with centre in the origin, so all singularities lie inside contour. I can't  find the easy way to calculate this, there must be something i don't know yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose you want $z^{5}+1$ in the denominator. There are $5$ fifth roots of $-1$ and they are al simple poles inside the contour. Apply Residue Theorem.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname{Res}}$To find the residue of $f(z) := \frac{1}{z^5+1}$ at a fifth root of $-1$, say $z_0$, note that $$\Res(f,z_0) = \frac{1}{5z_0^4} \color{blue}{= \frac{z_0}{5z_0^5} = -\frac{z_0}{5}},$$ since $z_0^5=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\zeta_k=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}5}\,,k=0,1,\dots,4$ be the $5$th roots of unity.

By the residue theorem,  we have $\oint_\gamma\dfrac1{z^5+1}\operatorname dz=\dfrac {2\pi i}5\sum_{k=0}^4\zeta_k$.  This  answer is gotten by using the formula for the residue of $f(z)=\dfrac {p(z)}{q(z)}$ at the simple pole $a$, given by $\fbox {$\operatorname{Res}(f,a)=\dfrac{p(a)}{ q'(a)}$}$.